# Get CentOS server capabilities in human-readable form using Python

Tags: python, linux, centos, human-readable, capsh

I am trying to analyze capabilities associated to my CentOS server. I have output of `ps aufxwwwZ` command and for each process the content of `/proc/$pid/status`. This is part of the dump of the configuration of the server I want to analyze.

I know I can get capabilities from `/proc/$pid/status` (lines beginning by ^Cap). I can use `capsh --decode` to get a human-readable form. However, I would like to implement this exclusively in python as part of a bigger script.

How is it possible to convert the capabilities mask to a human-readable list of capabilities without having to force users to install specific tools and launching `subprocess` stuff ?

I have tried to understand how the parsing is done reading [linux/capability.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/capability.h). Interesting parts :

```
#define CAP_TO_INDEX(x) ((x) >> 5)        /* 1 << 5 == bits in __u32 */
#define CAP_TO_MASK(x)  (1 << ((x) & 31)) /* mask for indexed __u32 */
```

So, for `cap_net_admin`, which is defined in this header file to `12`, 
I use `CAP_TO_MASK`, `((12) & 31)` gives 4096 :

```
printf("%d", 1 << ((12) & 31));
```

However, this is not what I observe for this specific capability in `/proc/pid/status` which is `1000`.

Is there a more straightforward converting process ?

Comment: so many thanks to whoever +1 my question; I would have loved any clue helping solving it however :/